# dojox.grid.DataGrid not working when extending

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm trying to extend a `dojox.grid.DataGrid` just to add some defaults in JS. I'm adding it to the page the declarative way like this:

Html Page

```
<table dojoType="my.DataGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="30px" field="num">N°</th>
            <th width="auto" field="email">E-mail</th>
            <th width="auto" field="name" editable="true">Full name</th>
            <th width="120px" field="hours" editable="true">Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS File

```
dojo.provide("my.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.declare("my.DataGrid", [ dojox.grid.DataGrid ], {
    summary: "My Not Working DataGrid"
});
```

It works perfectly using `dojox.grid.DataGrid` but when I try to extend it, nothing shows up. I'm using dojo 1.6 (I know it's old, I can't upgrade it). I know it is working because I can access it via dijit.registry._hash but It won't render even calling `render()` or `startup()`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to set a width and height style to your Grid? This maybe solves the Problem.

Comment: adding width and height only makes it show the default background color for the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, I'm trying to extend the functionality of the grid but when I do it, it doesn't render. Can't use a more recent version of dojo either. Stuck in 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

in the DataGrid.js there are tow functions for rendering the widget from html-markup.

```
dojox.grid.DataGrid.cell_markupFactory
```

and

```
dojox.grid.DataGrid.markupFactory
```

you have to override them in your new Grid class with your own package name e.g

```
com.mycompany.grid.MyGrid.cell_markupFactory
```

and

```
com.mycompany.grid.MyGrid.markupFactory
```

then it works!!!